# how to remove multiple table row using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have dynamic table with unique row id e.g , , , also having checkbox for every row.

using jquery i fetch all the selected ids (comma separated, e.g 1,25,4) of that checkboxes. All i need to remove those selected tr's after jquery success.
 see my below code:

getting comma separated ids:

```
var ids = $(".chk:checked").map(function() {
                    return this.id;
                }).get().join(",");
```

condition:

```
if(response == 0){
                            alert('Sorry! There is some problem in server, try again.');
                            return false;
                        }else {
                            alert("Successfully removed from library.");
                            $('#tr_'+ids).remove();
                        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a working snippet (using the [<>] button when you edit your post) with some HTML content ?

Comment: i have edit my question and also attached image, please have a look

Comment: An image is not helpful to actually launch the script, see what happens, and debug the problem… Can't you add some of your HTML to create a snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add all ids to an array you can then use this to remove the rows

```
$.each(ids, function(key, val){
    $('#tr_' + val).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#tr_'+ids)` would end up looking like `$('#tr_1,3,7,9')` which is an invalid selector

You could do things like:

```
$("tr").has('.chk:checked').remove()

// OR 

$(".chk:checked").closest('tr').remove()
```